# Droppable inside iframe with scrollable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

When you have a draggable outside an iFrame and a droppable inside an iFrame, when using the iframeFix option it works. But when you introduce an scrollable div around the iframe the coordinates of the droppable are not updated and remain at the original position before it was scrolled.

e.g. the top left in this example

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js""></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
        $("iframe").load(function () {
            var iframe = $(this).contents();
            iframe.find('#iframe_container').droppable(
            {
                iframeFix: true,
                drop: function (event, ui) { alert('dropped'); }
            });
        });
        $('#drag').draggable({iframeFix: true});
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:400px; height:200px; overflow:auto">
    <iframe src="iframe.html" style="width:400px; height:400px;"></iframe>
     </div>
    <div  style="width:20px; height:20px; background-color: #808080" id="drag"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

iframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="iframe_container" style=" width: 40px; height: 40px; background-color: #0094ff">
     </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening or know a workaround for this issue?